# dynamic allocation of an object containing a vecto

Tags: c++, vector, dynamic, allocation

I tried to do this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct test{
    vector<int> tab;
};

int main(){
    test* obj2;
    obj2 = (test*) malloc(sizeof(test));


    obj2->tab.push_back(1); 
    obj2->tab.push_back(2);
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        cout<<obj2->tab[i]<<" ";
    }
}
```

I works, but I don't understand why.
When I allocate obj2 I ask for some memory with an empty vector. But then, I add some stuff in that vector, so the memory taken by obj2 increased, didn't it ?
I'd like to know why it works, and even if it does, is it still a good thing to do ?

Edit :
 This is an example. I add a vector in a struct that is allocated by a malloc because it was written in C before and I can not change all the allocations. I just passed the file to a cpp one.

Comment: Don't use `malloc` in C++, use `new`. When you use `malloc` you ask for some memory that doesn't contain anything yet, and trying to use an object that doesn't exist has undefined behaviour.

Comment: I forgot to say why I use malloc, I'll change it right now

Comment: You *can't* create a `std::vector` with `malloc`. You need to change `malloc` to `new` and `free` to `delete`.

Comment: in your code you never construct an instance of type `test` nor a `vector`. `malloc` is not to create objects. The code has undefined behavior, it just appears to work

Comment: If you want to change the code written in `C` to `C++`, you have to change `malloc` to `new`.

Comment: @molbdnilo I can't change them. That is the problem. Should I use a dynamic tab and use realloc when I need to add something ?

Comment: Ok finally I got the permission to change the malloc/free to new/delete so all is ok now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Oops, there is a strong difference between creating a dynamic object and allocating its memory with malloc: the construction of the object.

In your code, the `test` object is never constructed, and as a consequence, the vector is not either: your code invokes Undefined Behaviour by using non initialized objects.

If you are forced to use a memory zone provided by a C module, you should considere using a *placement new* to have the object fully constructed:

```
test* obj2;
obj2 = (test*) malloc(sizeof(test));     // obj2 points to uninitialized memory

obj2 = new((void *) obj2) test;          // construct an object in the allocated memory
                                         //  including its subobjects (here the vector member)

obj2->tab.push_back(1);                  // no longer UB...
```

Answer (score 0):

> It works

No, it doesn't. It's undefined behaviour that seems to work.

> but I don't understand why

To understand why this (seems to) work, we have to take a look at the structure of `std::vector`. A implementation could use 3 pointers:

- Start of allocated memory
- End of used memory
- End of allocate memory

Now you allocate a number of bytes via `malloc()` and interpret them as a class with those 3 pointers. If we assume a pointer to be 4byte large you allocate 12 bytes and interpret the first 4 bytes as the pointer to the start of allocated memory, the next 4 bytes as the pointer to the end of used memory and the last 4 bytes as the pointer to the end of allocated memory.

This *might* work if the allocated memory happens to contain reasonable values. But it really is undefined behaviour. For example with c++ it happened to contain all zeroes, which resulted in all three pointers being `nullptr`, which is probably what the constructor would have done too.

But in Visual Studio the memory was *not* initialized to zero, which resulted in random values for all three pointers, which causes a segfault.

So, why does this (seem to) work? Because the memory you allocated contained reasonable values by pure luck.

> I ask for some memory with an empty vector

No, you just allocate memory and *interpreted* it as an vector. That the vector is empty (or even works) is only luck as detailed above. It happened that the vector ended in the same state as it would have after calling the constructor.

> But then, I add some stuff in that vector, so the memory taken by obj2 increased, didn't it ?

No, it doesn't. The size of any object is known and fixed at compile time. A `std::vector` only manages heap-memory, e.g. dynamically allocated memory. So it doesn't increase it's own size, nor the size of the struct containing it, but it's only increasing the the size of memory it manages.

> is it still a good thing to do ?

No, absolutely not. If you need dynamic memory, use a container, smart pointers or at tthe very least `new`.